# Change background color of UIViewController from other UIViewController

Tags: ios

I have allocated a `UIviewController` ontop of another one. I would like to change the color of the other one from this new controller, but I don't know how. I tried this:

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
NSLog(@"slider value = %f", sender.value);

ViewController1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(160/sender.value) green:(97/sender.value) blue:(5/sender.value) alpha:0.6];
}
```

and imported the `ViewController1`, but it gives an error. If I put `self.view` it will work fine but not on `ViewController1`. How can I do this?

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: property view not found on object of type UIViewcontroller

Comment: Please post the code on how your are "importing" the view controller. There is not enough info in what you have posted so far.

Comment: I have just added #import "View..."

Comment: You say you are "allocating" a view controller on top of another one. Please post that code.

Comment: UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardInfo"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self presentPopupViewController:vc animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];

Comment: @Alessandro Please stop adding the xcode tag to all of your questions. Read the description of the Xcode tag. It rarely applies to your questions.

Comment: According to your comment "and imported the `ViewController1`", this means `ViewController1` is a class, instead of an instance, and assuming `vc` is the instance (by your code in last comment), you should try changing this: `ViewController1.view.backgroundColor = ...` to this `vc.view.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are actually storing a reference to the UIViewController you want to change the background color of. Try creating a property for the view controller that you are displaying and then do something like this:

```
@implementation MyPoppingController

-(void)showViewController
{
    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardInfo" bundle:nil];        
    self.myPopController = [sb instantiateInitialViewController]; 
    self.myPopController.myPresentingViewController = self;
    [self presentPopupViewController:self.myPopController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade]; 
}
@end


@interface MyPoppedController

@property(strong, nonatomic) MyPopppingController *myPresentingViewController;

@end

@implementation MyPoppedController

-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    self.myPresentingViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(160/sender.value) green:(97/sender.value) blue:(5/sender.value) alpha:0.6];
}

@end
```

Comment: ops, no... the backgroundcolor I want to change is not the myPopController, but the View controller from which I am presenting it. And I want to change it from the myPopController

Comment: Ok, modified it. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: Yes thanks it does. I didn't know there was a property presentingViewController. Now I just need to fix the error I get with this line: myPopController.presentingViewController = self; assignment to readonly property

Comment: I may have used a reserved propertyname. Change it to myPresentingViewController.

Comment: I have and it doesn't seem that myPresentingViewController exists. Xcode asks me to change it with PresentingViewController which still gives an error

Comment: You need to create the property yourself in the interface of your view controller that is being Popped.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I'm wasting your time but I don't seem to be getting it. In MyPoppingController I still get an error at myPresentingViewController. How do I access the property created in MyPoppedController?

Comment: You need to create the property. Do you know how to create a property? I actually posted it. Look at my answer.

Comment: I did add the property ro the mypoppedcontroller. i have done everything you told me, but still in mypoppingcontroller I can't access it

Comment: The line   myPopController.myPresentingViewController = self; is causing trouble

Comment: I updated the answer. Also, please edit your question and add code the header file for your popping view controller.